# How to make a loop iterate from middle to beginning of a list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a loop iterate in a list from the middle of a list's index to the beginning using the `for i in range()` loop. How would I do that? Say we have a list

```
a = ['apple', 'peach', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana']
```

How would I iterate from `'orange'` to `'apple'`?

My prediction:

```
for i in range(a[orange], 0)
```

I'm new to programming, sorry for the obvious question.

Comment: First of all, you iterate through lists by index (where the index starts at zero), so `a[orange]` (or `a["orange"]`, for that matter), would result in an error.

Comment: Because a["orange"] world result in a string?

Comment: Because `a['orange']` is dict-style access, not list-style access, and would result in an error.

Comment: `"orange"` is the third element of `a`. That means that it's at index 2 (indices start at 0, not 1). So, `a[2] == "orange"`.

Comment: Jack, so can I just write range(a[index of the fruit], a[0])? This will work right? As it will iterate from whatever index to the beginning?

Comment: No. `a[2]` is a string. In particular, it's the string `"orange"`. Thus, it's not an appropriate argument to the `range` function. What I believe you can do, though, is `sorted(range(a.index("orange")), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there... use `list.index` to find the value, then reverse a slice from your list, eg:

```
a = ['apple', 'peach', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana']
b = a[a.index('orange')::-1]
# ['orange', 'peach', 'apple']
```

You'd probably want to throw in a bit of error handling for where the value isn't found in the list, eg:

```
try:
    b = a[a.index('not_in_list')::-1]
except ValueError:
    b = [] # or other sensible result
```

Then maybe a helper function:

```
def backwards_from(lst, value):
    try:
        return lst[lst.index(value)::-1]
    except ValueError:
        return [] # or other sensible result

for item in backwards_from(a, 'orange'):
    print item
#orange
#peach
#apple

for item in backwards_from(a, 'cabbage'):
    print item
# nothing to print
```

If you really, really want to use `range`, then you start with the index, decrementing by -1, until the start of the list (which is `-1` because the end isn't included in the range), eg:

```
for idx in range(a.index('orange'), -1, -1):
    print a[idx]
```

Comment: good job actually decoding the question into something with a nice clean answer

Comment: Note that using `index` is only necessary if you don't know the starting point. A simple reverse and slice may be more readable here if it is known in advance. (OP is new to programming and does not state this, so this may be an overcomplication of the loop necessary.)

Comment: Can you please explain what you did here: b = a[a.index('orange')::-1] This seems like what I'm looking for, I don't need anything else.

Comment: Note, if you don't need to get a `list` from the `backwards_from` function, you can do `return reversed(lst[:lst.index(value) + 1])` which may or may not be more intuitive to some people...

Comment: @Simon `list`s have a `.index()` method which returns the index of the first matching value (in this case `orange` which returns 2). So the code is effectively `a[2::-1]` which takes from the 2nd index, backwards (what the `-1` is for)

Comment: But can I just write range(a[index of the fruit], a[0])? This will work right? As it will iterate from whatever index to the beginning?

Comment: @SimonFraser I've updated to include an example of how to use `range`

Comment: Thank you, the last tip was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Slicing works nicely here:

```
>>> a[len(a)//2::-1]
['orange', 'peach', 'apple']
```

So, to iterate over the objects:

```
>>> for fruit in a[len(a)//2::-1]:
...   print fruit
... 
orange
peach
apple
```

Note that `len(a)//2` is the length of the list divided by 2 (truncated to an integer) and the `-1` part of the slice means iterate backwards.

Comment: @SimonFraser -- You might want to take a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).  The section on strings talks about it, but it also works for any python sequence (`str`, `list`, `tuple`, `bytearray`, `xrange`, ...)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
for fruit in list(reversed(fruit_list))[2:]:
    print(fruit)
```

?

Although you can use slice notation with a negative step `[::-1]` to reverse an iterable, Python provides the handy and readable `reversed` built-in function to do the same. From there, you can just slice to the portion of the list you want.

This is also more Pythonic, since you iterate directly over the elements of the list. Generally, you don't need to keep up with the indices yourself in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range (len(list)/2,-1): print list[x]
```

Comment: This will fail on Python 3 and result in no iteration on Python 2.

Comment: See for loop at the end of this site http://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop to make a backward running loop